# Transforming integrals on a manifold

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, change-of-variable, pullback, pushforward

Let $\widehat\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ be differentiable manifolds, and let $\Phi: \widehat\Gamma \to \Gamma$ be a smooth, bijective, orientation-preserving map.

I understand that for a real valued function $\omega$ on $\Gamma$, then
$$\int_\Gamma = \int_{\widehat\Gamma}\Phi^*\omega = \int_{\widehat\Gamma}\omega\circ\Phi \tag{i}$$
where $\Phi^*$ is the pullback operator such that $\Phi^*\omega \equiv \omega\circ\Phi$. ***(Is this right?)***

Please I need help with how to approach an integrand that has functions defined on both $\Gamma$ and $\widehat\Gamma$ (these are identified by a hat). **In particular, I have these integrals on $\widehat\Gamma$ and need to transform them to integrals on $\Gamma$**. The integrals look something like these:

$$I_1 = \int_{\widehat\Gamma}(\widehat{n}\cdot \widehat{J}T\widehat{F}\widehat{n})(\widehat{u}\cdot\widehat{n})\;d\widehat{s}$$
$$I_2 = \int_{\widehat\Gamma}(\widehat{a}\cdot\widehat{n})(\widehat{u}\cdot\widehat{n})\;d\widehat{s}$$
$$I_3 = \int_{\widehat\Gamma}\widehat{a}\cdot\widehat{n}\;d\widehat{s}$$
where $\widehat{F} = \widehat\nabla\Phi$, $J=\textrm{Det}\widehat{F} > 0$, and $\widehat{n}$ is a unit normal vector to the surface element $d\widehat{s}$ of $\widehat\Gamma$, $\widehat{a}$ and $\widehat{u}$ are vectors defined on $\widehat{\Gamma}$; and $T$ is a second order tensor defined on $\Gamma$.

**For $I_2$ and $I_3$ here is what I am thinking**: Define the pushforward operator $\varphi = \Phi^{-1}$ then
$$I_2 = \int_{\widehat\Gamma}\biggl(\left((\widehat{a}\circ\varphi)\circ\Phi\right)\cdot\left((\widehat{n}\circ\varphi)\circ\Phi\right)\biggr)\biggl(\left((\widehat{u}\circ\varphi)\circ\Phi\right)\cdot\left((\widehat{n}\circ\varphi)\circ\Phi\right)\biggr)\;d\widehat{s}$$
$$=\int_\Gamma \Bigl((\widehat{a}\circ\varphi)\cdot(\widehat{n}\circ\varphi)\Bigr)\Bigl((\widehat{u}\circ\varphi)\cdot(\widehat{n}\circ\varphi)\Bigr)\;ds \tag{ii}$$
by applying (i). And similarly,
$$I_3 = \int_\Gamma (\widehat{a}\circ\varphi)\cdot(\widehat{n}\circ\varphi)\;ds \tag{iii}$$

Further, the pushforward operator on a contravariant vector $\widehat{a}$ and a second-order tensor $\widehat{T}$ (which maps contravarian vectors to contravariant vectors) are respectively defined:
$$\varphi^*{\widehat a} = \widehat{a}\circ\varphi = \widehat{F}\widehat{a}, \qquad\qquad\qquad
\varphi^*{\widehat T} = \widehat{T}\circ\varphi = \widehat{F}^{-T}\widehat{T}\widehat{F}^{-1},$$
then I can simply calculate each pushed-forward term in the integral e.g. $\widehat{a}\circ\varphi$ and substitute into (ii) and (iii). ***Is any of this correct?***

For $I_1$ I am not sure how to proceed since $T$ in the integrand is defined on $\Gamma$ and not $\widehat\Gamma$.

*I apologize if my statements are not rigorous. I'm a programmer, I don't have a math background.*

Comment: I haven't read it completely, but in (i), $\Phi^*\omega$ is not necessarily $\omega \circ \Phi$. This is only true if $\omega$ is a $0$-form, i.e a real valued function on the manifold, but otherwise if it is a form of higher degree, then it's not true anymore.

Comment: Yes it's a real-valued function! Thanks, I am making the correction. P.S. You said you didn't read it completely. Was it too long? How would you suggest I can improve the question?

Comment: No, it's more that I'm not too comfortable with integration on manifolds (there are soo many subtleties lol) so I doubt I'm the best person to answer this question

Comment: Are $\Gamma$ and $\widehat{\Gamma}$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$? The unit normal isn't intrinsically defined, so it can't be pushed/pulled like tensors. Also, what is meant here by $\widehat{\nabla}\Phi$? I'm not sure how to interpret the derivative of a smooth map in the expression you have.

Comment: Thanks, @Kajelad. Actually this is from a problem in 2D and 3D in continuum mechanics. $\Gamma$ and $\widehat\Gamma$ are surfaces in both i.e. 1D line in 2D, and 2D surface in 3D. Pushing normal vectors? I had no idea. Thanks. The gradient of the deformation map $\widehat{F} = \widehat{\nabla}\Phi$ is the Jacobian matrix of the deformation, describing how a particle changes position during motion/deformation. Given a "reference position vector" $d\widehat{x}$ in $\widehat\Gamma$ and a corresponding "deformed position vector" $dx$ in $\Gamma$, then $F$ is the matrix $\dfrac{dx}{d\widehat{x}}$